# Different wrap text between horizontal and vertical

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, text, material-ui

I'm facing an issue very obvious.
I think that more than 1 000 000 people already asked this question, but I didn't succeed to find my answer on Google :'(

I wanted to have my text wrapped in one of my cards, this is what I got now :

[image: Image of my card]

My CSS is currently :

```
overflow: hidden;
white-space: pre;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

So, what I want :

- My text is going to a new line when there is a line break in the text: ok
- My text has 3 points ellipsis when there is a vertical overflow: ok
- My text is going to line when there is a horizontal overflow: not ok (see line 2 in the image)

How can I do this?

Comment: insert your html pls

Answer (score 0):

I found my way using webkit-line-clamp, helping myself with this useful newspaper [here](http://hackingui.com/front-end/a-pure-css-solution-for-multiline-text-truncation/).

The final CSS is:

```
overflow: hidden;
white-space: pre-line;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-line-clamp: 3;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
```